# How to fill time windows without data in Kinesis analytics

Tags: amazon-web-services, analytics, amazon-kinesis, stream-processing

Is there any way to fire kinesis analytics when there is no data coming on the stream? Like a periodic run despite there is data or not?

I have a data stream from a sensor that looks like:

```
[
  {
     "timestamp": "2011/09/01 22:30",
     "reading": 1
  },
  {
     "timestamp": "2011/10/01 22:31",
     "reading": 0
  }
]
```

My use case is to calculate in real-time the seconds that a `reading` has been 1 in buckets of 1 minute.

Please, I plan to do this using just Kinesis Analytics SQL or AWS tools and not a third party service like drools or any other startup out there.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You are probably asking the wrong question [**What is the XY problem?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Focus more on what you need instead how would you do it .

Comment: The example schema is posted with the question, it only has timestamp and reading which is an integer with either 1 or 0. There is no DB schema in Kinesis analytics, data comes in a JSON stream

Comment: JSON also have a structure. The problem is you dont provide enough information to understand the logic

Comment: Updated the question a little bit, feel free to suggest any edits

Comment: I still don't understand your "big problem". Because looks like you can calculate the time between `22:30` and `22:31`

Comment: When there is data periodically the calculation is accurate. The big problem comes when the reading=1 for let says a month without changing to 0. have you used Kinesis Analytics at all?

Comment: I havent use kinesis, but move around with db very confortable. If you have a big problem then you show the data with the big problem, not the data you already know how to handle.

Comment: Updated it again, I'm also very comfy with DBs and SQL but this is a question very specific to how Kinesis Analytics works

Comment: My bad actually to tag it with SQL, sorry

Comment: Good luck then. I still think your question doesn't show what is the "big problem"